# Check memory usage of radixsort C++

Tags: c++, memory

I have implemented radix sort in c++

```cpp
...

void *countSort(int *tab, int size, int exp, string *comp, bool *stat) { 
    int output[size]; 
    int i, index, count[10] = {0}; 
    sysinfo(&amem);
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++){
        index =  (tab[i]/exp)%10;
        count[index]++; 
    }


    for (i = 1; i < 10; i++) 
        count[i] += count[i - 1]; 

    for (i = size - 1; i >= 0; i--) { 
        index = count[ (tab[i]/exp)%10 ] - 1;
        output[index] = tab[i]; 
        count[ (tab[i]/exp)%10 ]--; 
    } 

    if((*comp).rfind("<",0) == 0){
        for (i = 0; i < size; i++){
            tab[i] = output[i]; 
            swap_counter++;
            if(!*stat){ fprintf(stderr, "przestawiam\n"); }
        }
    }else{
        for (i = 0; i < size; i++){
            tab[i] = output[size-i-1]; 
            swap_counter++;
            if(!*stat){ fprintf(stderr, "przestawiam\n"); }
        }
    }
} 

void *radix_sort(int size, int *tab, string *comp, bool *stat) { 
    int m; 
    auto max = [tab, size](){
        int m = tab[0]; 
        for (int i = 1; i < size; i++) {
            if (tab[i] > m) 
                m = tab[i]; 
        }  
        return m;
    };
    m = max();

    for (int exp = 1; m/exp > 0; exp *= 10) 
        countSort(tab, size, exp, comp, stat); 
} 

...

int main(){
   int tab = (int *) malloc(n*sizeof(int));
   for(int n = 100; n <=10000; n+=100){
      generate_random_tab(tab, n);
      radix_sort(sorted_tab, 0, n-1, ">=", 1);
      free(tab);
   }
}
```

Now I want to check and print out information of how much memory radix sort uses.
I want to do this to compare how much of memory different sorting algorithms uses.
How to achieve this?

I was given a hint to use a sysinfo() to analyze how system memory usage changes but I couldn't achieve constant results.
(I'm working on linux)

Comment: Do you mean allocation (there isn't any, it's done in place) or stack (count max recursion depth + estimate size of local variables and arguments in quick_sort)? You can possibly get allocation statistics out of valgrind or similar.

Comment: I've changed the topic to radix sort. My task is described as "calculate total memory usage of radix sort and other sort algorithms that you've implemented and compare the results" it doesn't specify if I should calculate allocation size or stack

Answer (score 0):

[`sysinfo`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sysinfo.2.html) only shows whole system memory, not individual process memory.

For process memory usage, you might try [`mallinfo`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/mallinfo.3.html), e.g.

```
struct mallinfo before = mallinfo();
// radix sort code
struct mallinfo after = mallinfo();
```

Now you may compare the various entries before and after your sorting code.
Be aware, that this doesn't include stack memory.

Although I don't know, how accurate these numbers are in a C++ context.

---

Testing a complete example

```
#include <malloc.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define SHOW(m) printf(#m "=%d-%d\n", after.m, before.m)

int main()
{
    struct mallinfo before = mallinfo();
    void *p1 = malloc(1000000);
    //int *p2 = new int[1000000];
    struct mallinfo after = mallinfo();
    SHOW(arena);
    SHOW(ordblks);
    SHOW(smblks);
    SHOW(hblks);
    SHOW(hblkhd);
    SHOW(usmblks);
    SHOW(fsmblks);
    SHOW(uordblks);
    SHOW(fordblks);
    SHOW(keepcost);
    return 0;
}
```

shows different values, depending on whether you use `malloc`

> arena=135168-0
>   ordblks=1-1
>   smblks=0-0
>   hblks=1-0
>   hblkhd=1003520-0
>   usmblks=0-0
>   fsmblks=0-0
>   uordblks=656-0
>   fordblks=134512-0
>   keepcost=134512-0

or `new`

> arena=135168-135168
>   ordblks=1-1
>   smblks=0-0
>   hblks=1-0
>   hblkhd=4001792-0
>   usmblks=0-0
>   fsmblks=0-0
>   uordblks=73376-73376
>   fordblks=61792-61792
>   keepcost=61792-61792

It looks like C++ (Ubuntu, GCC 9.2.1) does some preallocation, but the relevant number seems to be `hblkhd` (on my machine).

Since your only dynamic allocation is at the beginning of main, you must do the first `mallinfo` there. Testing only the radix sort code reveals, that there are no additional dynamic memory allocations.

Comment: It results in printing only 0 :/

Answer (score 0):

Your program has linear memory usage `malloc(n*sizeof(int))` and `int output[size];` --- one of them on heap, the other on stack, so basically you don't need to make run-time measurements as you can calculate it easily.

As you are on Linux, for more complicated cases there is e.g. [massif](https://www.valgrind.org/info/tools.html#massif) tool in valgrind, but it is focused on heap measurements  (which in normal cases in which you want to measure memory usage is enough, as stack is usually to small for serious amounts of data).